# Azure AD Application can have SPA or Web App or we can have both?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, msal.js, azure-authentication

Azure AD Application can have SPA or Web App or we can have both?
i have create app in azure ad and that have both
web and api and both have local host url.

1. so web application redirect uri :localhost:/5020 added platform  web
2. web api redirect uri :localhost:/5030 added this will
   web api platform

but it giving me error with react msal.js
"Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type"

Answer (score -1):

1. SPA app is actually  written in JavaScript which control the UI
   elements to sign in users and acquire tokens or even call the web
   apis directly from the browser using the javascript. Such
   applications must be registered **under SPA** while registering in azure
   ad app registration.
2. Where as web apps also do render pages from HTML and javascript ,but calling web
   API's is done on backend. So they must be registered under web app platform.

So please change the **App registration -> Authentication->platform type to SPA**  if it only uses Java script (ex: angular, react etc) instead of Web.
Or change it to web otherwise.
[image]

Also after correcting that, please make sure you are not using [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) for your SPA App i.e.; (using client secret).Use [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) instead in  that case.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply
cant i add same url in web app and spa cos my legacy app is in adal js and using implicit flow so do implicit flow required call back url or not ?

as my existing setup have :
localhost:/5020 added in  web redirects
but now when i use msal and use redirects with 
spa localhost:/5020 its not working

Comment: Please  check URIs type in the Manifest file to be Spa .The implicit grant flow is not supported in MSAL.js 2.0+but MSAL.js 1.0, supports the implicit grant flow.Plesae check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-app-registration#redirect-uri-msaljs-10-with-implicit-flow)

Comment: but if there is one url also with local host in web application its not allowing any other port with local host also in api call backs

Comment: One can have a mix of the two. Both server render and client side render. And wanting login logic done client side, without the app being an SPA. Then what to chose?